# Re-filling textboxes with their own value on submit

Tags: java, jsp

So I've got this "register" form, where you have to fill in your account/personal information. And I have server-side validation on this, but I want the textboxes to be filled with the same values as they were filled with after the person submits ( and it fails the validation ) for example " wrong format of email " if missing a @..

This is what my JSP page looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="Controller?theregform" id="regForm">
<tr>
    <td><label for="firstName">* First name</label></td>
    <td><input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="lastName">* Last name</label></td>
    <td><input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="email">* Email</label></td>
    <td><input id="email" name="email" type="email" required  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="repeatEmail">* Repeat Email</label></td>
    <td><input id="repeatEmail" name="repeatEmail" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="lblEmail" type="hidden"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="phone">* Phone</label></td>
    <td><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="address">* Address</label></td>
    <td><input id="adress" name="address" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="city">* City</label></td>
    <td><input id="city" name="city" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="adressCounty">* State</label></td>
    <td><input id="adressCounty" name="adressCounty" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="zipCode" >* Zip/Postal Code</label></td>
    <td><input id="zipCode" name="zipCode" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<button type="submit" form="regForm"class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>

</form>
```

If something is unclear about the question please use the comment section and I will try to explain better.

Comment: are you using any framework for this?

Comment: @satya nope, we are not using any framework

Comment: Are you doing client side or server side validation?

Comment: @satya  server-side validation, on email we're doing both though, just for the " view " .

Comment: This would all be so easy and out of the box if you use a library like knockout. And it does not have a steep learning curve either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EL(Expression Language) `${param.fieldName}` to re-populate the form fields:

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="${param.firstName}"/>
```

You can set request attribute for displaying the error messages. In validation code, for wrong email.

```
request.setAttribute("emailError", "Invalid email id");
```

In jsp page:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="${param.email}"/>
<span style="color:red;">${emailError}</span>
```

Comment: This looks good, I'm gonna try this out.. what does EL stand for?

Comment: This line - value="${param.firstName}"/> , was exactly what I was looking for :)